# Segmentation fault while using vector<pair<int,int>>

Tags: c++, vector, std-pair

Why this code of mine is giving `segmentation fault`? I am not able to get where I am going wrong, to me it seems fine. Any help will be great, thank you.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector <pair<int,int>> v;
    
    int arr[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
    
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        v[i]={arr[i],i};
    }
    
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
    cout<<v[i].first<<"\n";
    
    }

}
```

Comment: Your vector is empty, so `v[i]` for any `i` is going to be out of bounds (thus always illegal).

Comment: replace `v[i]={arr[i],i};` with `v.at(i)={arr[i],i};`.  Then you will get your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vector <pair<int,int>> v;` initializes `v` as an empty `vector`, it contains no elements. Then in `for` loops `v[i]={arr[i],i};` and `v[i].first` lead to UB.

You could use `push_back` or `emplace_back` instead.

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    v.push_back({arr[i],i}); // add element to v
    // or
    // v.emplace_back(arr[i],i);
}
```

Or make `v` containing 5 elements in advance.

```
vector <pair<int,int>> v(5); // initialize v as containing 5 elements
...
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    v[i]={arr[i],i};         // assignment on element
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems you dont know how to work with `std::vector`. `std::vector` is not like ordinary array you should use methods like `push_back()`

see more information [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).